# Is there a universal totally disconnected Polish space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

A topological space $X$ is called *totally disconnected* if for any distinct points $x,y\in X$ there exists a clopen set $U\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$.

In [1973](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm79/fm79127.pdf) Roman Pol proved that every separable metrizable space $M$ containing a topological copy of any totally disconnected separable metrizable space, contains a topological copy of the Hilbert cube. This result of Pol shows that there is no universal totally disconnected separable metrizable spaces. On the other hand, the Cantor cube is a universal totally disconnected compact metrizable space.

> **Problem.** Is there a totally disconnected Polish space containing a topological copy of each totally disconnected Polish space?

Comment: Is a countable product of countable discrete sets a possible candidates, or do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @YCor The countable product of discrete spaces is zero-dimensional. On the other hand, there exist totally disconnected Polish space of arbitrarily high dimension, including strongly infinite-dimensional, see e.g. http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v07/tp07113.pdf